# Are there any in built CUDA functions which allows a CUDA kernel to report error to the host code?

Tags: c++, cuda, gpu, gpgpu, nvidia

I am writing a CUDA kernel to perform hashing. Once I get an input, I first try hashing it with a predefined hash bucket size and during hashing if an overflow happens then I need to re-do the hashing using a larger bucket size. So I am wondering if there is any in built cuda function that allows me to report an error to the host code if a bucket overflow happens. I know that I can write something to a predefined memory location and then make the host code read it, but I would prefer to use some in built primitives if available.

Comment: I don't think there is anything no. As you said, you'll have to write something somewhere and then read it from the host.

Answer (score 2):

CUDA has [assertion support](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#assertion) on all curently supported hardware (sm_20 and newer). As per the documentation, it is legal to do something like this:

```
__global__ void testAssert(void)
{
    int is_one = 1;
    int should_be_one = 0;
    // This will have no effect
    assert(is_one);
    // This will halt kernel execution 
    assert(should_be_one);
}
```

You might be able to leverage this for signalling error conditions to the calling host code.